# Compute the values inside the GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to compute the values inside the GROUP_CONCAT?

For example, here is my query:

```
SELECT users.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(written.score separator ' - ') as Wscore,
       student_subject.*
FROM users
  JOIN written ON users.idnumber=written.idnumber
  JOIN student_subject ON users.idnumber=student_subject.idnumber
WHERE
      student_subject.teacher='$login_session'
  AND student_subject.section='$section'
  AND student_subject.level='$level'
  AND student_subject.year='$year'
  AND student_subject.subject='$subject'
GROUP BY users.idnumber
```

which gives this output:

[image]

I would like the `TOTAL` column to be populated with the sum of the `written_score` values.

Table 'written' looks like:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean compute the values inside group concat?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have a table written and column scores.,. what I want is to compute the total scores on that table., and show also the sum of all scores

Comment: add SUM(written.score) as total to your query.

Comment: where the same mdamia thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a query that solved my problem:

```
SELECT users.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(written.score separator ' - ') as Wscore,
       student_subject.*,
       SUM(written.score) as total 
FROM users
  JOIN written ON users.idnumber=written.idnumber
  JOIN student_subject ON users.idnumber=student_subject.idnumber
WHERE
      student_subject.teacher='$login_session'
  AND student_subject.section='$section'
  AND student_subject.level='$level'
  AND student_subject.year='$year'
  AND student_subject.subject='$subject'
GROUP BY users.idnumber
```

The key change was to add `SUM(written.score) as total` to the select list.  It produces correct-looking results:

[image]